How to rewrite an URL with an nginx reverse proxy while preserving functionality of the website referenced?
I currently try to evaluate if it is possible to deploy two instances of the web application Mayan EDMS to an URL scheme as follows:

http://dms.example.org/one/
http://dms.example.org/two/

Both instances do not need to know anything about each other, i.e. they live in isolation from each other. As far as I understand (I do not have any experience in this area) a reverse HTTP proxy is required to achieve such a URL mapping..
I created a lab setup with two Mayan EDMS instances using Docker (as recommended). Both instances are reachable, both from my localhost running Docker as well as from other hosts on the local network. They can be accessed directly (i.e. no reverse proxy involved) via the following URLs. Note that 192.168.1.42 is the public IPv4 address of the host running Docker.

Instance #1: http://192.168.1.42:49160
Instance #2: http://192.168.1.42:49161

Next, I'd tried to implement the following mapping for the URLs using nginx:

http://192.168.1.42:49152/one/ should behave exactly as http://192.168.1.42:49160
http://192.168.1.42:49152/two/ should behave exactly as http://192.168.1.42:49161

I made some progress, but I'm unable to make http://192.168.1.42:49152/one/ properly function (I assume due to incorrect hyperlinks). The rewrite does basically work (I do see "some" page" content), but the page is more or less broken (CSS, hyperlinks, 404s, etc.)
I'm using nginx in a Docker container. Here is what I've come up with so far:
nginx-reverse-proxy/docker-compose.yml:
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "49152:80"
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

nginx-reverse-proxy/default.conf:
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
        # websocket/reload
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

        # This does display parts of the original webite, but not all URLs are properly rewritten.
        #
        # Also note that "http://<ip>:49152/one/" has to be entered into the browser,
        # "http://<ip>:49152/one" does **not** work.
        location /one/ {
            proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:49160/;

            # This fixes "some" hyperlinks as well as CSS, but the site is still not working properly.
            #sub_filter 'href="/' 'href="/one/';
            #sub_filter 'src="/' 'src="/one/';
            #sub_filter_once off;

            # This does not seem to have any effect at all.
            #rewrite ^/one(.*)$ $1 break;
        }
    }

I've already tried quite a lot (as you can see in the comments of the default.conf file), but I'm unable to obtain a fully-functional website http://192.168.1.120:49152/one/ that behaves as the "original" http://host.docker.internal:49160.
Note that I've also looked into existing SO question, e.g.:

Ngixn rewrite and reverse proxy to docker container
How to properly serve a Django site under a Sub URI in Apache?

Questions:

Is it possible to "fix" the URL rewrite using nginx? What do I need to modify in the config file?

May it be impossible to implement the desired URL scheme using paths, because the web application (Mayan EDMS) does not support a deployment to an URL?

If the answer to question #2 is "yes": What's the alternative? Use a subdomain instead, e.g. http://one.dms.example.org?

What about aspects such as Cross-Site-Request-Forgery (CSRF)? A detection for that should be implemented in Mayan EDMS. Can this also be worked around using a reverse proxy?

Is there any other solution ot the problem than a reverse proxy? Note that Mayan EDMS must run in Docker, i.e. its frontend is only exposed via its port (I couldn't find any setting that allows configuring an URL path, maybe ORGANIZATIONS_INSTALLATION_URL).
Edit: I've found https://gitlab.com/mayan-edms/mayan-edms/-/issues/1045 but I wasn't able to modify the behavior by changing the two mentioned Mayan EDMS environment variables.



Note that this is not really the answer to this question (because it does not involve nginx). Nonetheless, this could be a sufficient workaround.
It seems using a reverse proxy is not necessary in order to serve Mayan EDMS using an URL subpath.
Mayan EDMS specifies two settings named ORGANIZATIONS_INSTALLATION_URL and ORGANIZATIONS_URL_BASE_PATH, which can be modified using environment variables. The environment variables have to be prefixed with MAYAN_. Quote from https://docs.mayan-edms.com/apps/smart_settings:

To pass a value via an environment variable append "MAYAN_" to the name of the settings option.

This means the following has to be set, either in the .env file or in the docker-compose.yml file (for the x-mayan-container service):
MAYAN_FRONTEND_HTTP_PORT=49160
MAYAN_ORGANIZATIONS_URL_BASE_PATH=one
MAYAN_ORGANIZATIONS_INSTALLATION_URL=http://dev.local:${MAYAN_FRONTEND_HTTP_PORT}

After restarting the Docker container, the Mayan EDMS instance is still available via localhost by accessing the following URL: http://localhost:49160/mayan/one
There is one issue, though: Accessing http://localhost:49160/mayan/one redirects to http://localhost:49160/mayan/one/authentication/login/?next=/mayan/one/home/ (which looks ok). But after successful login a redirect to http://localhost:49160/#/ happens and an empty white page (the HTML source only contains a <script> element with some stuff) is displayed. After manually accessing http://localhost:49160/mayan/one the instance can be used, though.
Additional resources:

Make mayan-edms work in a subdirectory
redirect fails on the login page when using a subdir

